# What is the SVN term for deleting changes?

Tags: svn

I made changes to a few files in SVN and I want to reverse the changes I made, i.e., have my version be the one in HEAD. What is the SVN term for that (so I can find it in tortoisesvn - I'm not sure if I should `revert`/`clean up`, etc.)?

Comment: "wan't" is not an english word. I assume, you mean "want".

Comment: @Marcel `wan't`, following normal English rules, is the contraction of `wa` and `not` ... of course.

Comment: It was typo - come on...

Comment: Yes, `revert` is how to "discard local changes". See the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to `svn revert`.

To revert all files in your working copy from the command line use the recursive parameter:  `svn revert -R $WC_ROOT`.  I'm not positive if the revert command in Tortoise is recursive by default but it should have an option for it.

Note that revert will not remove any files that aren't part of the revision you have checked out.  For instance, if you used `svn add` to add a file that hasn't been committed or have a file in the path of your working copy that hasn't been added yet, they will still exist with a "?" status even after you issue your revert command.

Here is some documentation on all commands available in subversion: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.ref

Answer (score 2):

`svn revert` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

i believe it's

```
svn revert filename
```